# Speeding Up git clone in Jenkins by downloading archive

Tags: github, jenkins

My Jenkins pipelines use the GitHub SCM module, which checks out my repo using git clone.

Recently though, I've been seeing frequent build failures due to intermittent network performance issues, leading to git clone timing out.

One solution would be if I could pull the repo down as a zipped archive instead, this would drastically reduce the download time.

My questions are:

a) Is this advisable (compared to using git clone)? 
b) How would I do this to get the same effect as git clone
c) is it possible to do this using the Git SCM plugin or similar plugin?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

If is a network problem you should fix the network problem.

But, if you can't maybe the solution is increase git clone timeout.

[image: GIT_TIMEOUT]

Again, the best solution is fix the network.